# PhpStorm - class names as strings suggestions

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete, phpstorm, intellisense

I have to write the following code (using `Zend\Filter\Inflector`):

```
$inflector = new Inflector(':string');
    $inflector->setRules([
        ':string' => [
            new StringToLower(),
            new UnderscoreToSeparator(),
            new DashToCamelCase(),
            new UpperCaseWords(),
        ]
    ]);
```

As you see, it uses 4 times the `new` keyword, immediately instantiating classes (following Zend Filter Interface). In this case autocomplete works fine, PhpStorm easily found what I wanted typing after `new`.

But better notation, using factories, is using strings, instead of direct instantiation using `new`:

```
 $inflector = new Inflector(':string');
    $inflector->setRules([
        ':string' => [
            'StringToLower',
            'UnderscoreToSeparator',
            'DashToCamelCase',
            'UpperCaseWords',
        ]
    ]);
```

Is there a way to have autocomplete for those strings? Maybe some annotation hint or something?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `UpperCaseWords::class`? The resulting value (that will be available during runtime) will be FQN.

I'm not familiar with Zend Framework so I'm just not sure if `Zend\Filter\Inflector` accepts FQN or it limited to/requires class names only (it should accept FQN ... so user-made classes would also be accepted/it's expected behaviour).

The benefit: refactoring / find usages will also be supported (since this is a piece of code and not just a string).

---

**In any case:** class name completion in strings should work **since 2017.1.4** (works fine here in current stable 2017.2.4).

You just invoke code completion one more time (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> twice (or whatever else shortcut you have there on your computer/OS for `Code | Completion | Basic`)) .. or just use <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Space</kbd> straight away (class name completion).

Obviously, it will work if completion is invoked on the beginning of the string. If it's in the middle/end of it (e.g. `"use [CLASS_NAME_EXPECTED_HERE]"`) -- type whole thing manually or try other completion methods (e.g. `Cyclic Expand Word` if such class name was already mentioned in current file).